# tools for reverse engineering for java

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

Is there any tool that can be used to generate the UML diagram from Java code. I am currently using STAR UML for the same. But the tool is unable to design the dependency like if one class calls another class, rest the class diagram is generated stating interfaces, classes, extended classes and all..

can anyone please help me for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Sparx Enterprise Architect.  It can import Java or C# nicely.   It also has a runtime feature that allows you to step through code and generate sequence diagrams.

Comment: . i have used the tool that u have mentioned but it is also not capable of achieving the flow sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java). It is not a UML tool. However, it will quickly draw a diagram of your code artifacts with all possible dependencies. Many people use it for reverse engineering and for digging into legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MagicDraw UML](http://www.magicdraw.com/) to achieve this. It's not free, but it's definitly worth the money.

Check out the trial version before buying.